# Uninstall GRUB from logical partition

Tags: linux, partitioning, multi-boot, grub

I'm multi-booting with Windows 7 x64 and (at least) Linux Mint. Because I hadn't yet made a backup of my MBR, when I installed Linux Mint on a logical partition, I told the installer to put GRUB on the partition instead of in the MBR. This turned out to be useless, as I need to use GRUB from a boot disk to get into the GRUB I installed...

Before installing it in the MBR, I'd like to get it out of the partition, preferably without wiping and reinstalling Linux. I don't relish the prospect of going through two layers of GRUB when I want to boot Linux.

How do I get it out, or what other options are available to me?

Comment: In your situation, I would nuke the system since it's a problem not in need of actual solving, unless you were to do this _a lot_.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once it's installed in the MBR, it should be able to boot Linux Mint without going through the GRUB in the logical partition. Installing GRUB to the MBR is completely safe as long as the Mint version is newish. GRUB can boot straight to Windows 7.

Also, GRUB's not really doing anything to the logical partition, so there's really no harm in leaving it.

Simply, the area it installed to can't be used for anything else anyway, so even if you did remove it, you wouldn't gain any space.